# Como identificar no código o método ou comando para exibir uma lista de dados no NavigationView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Eu encontrei esse código na `hithub` sobre um visualizador de bordados segue o [link do projeto](https://github.com/Embroidermodder/MobileViewer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/embroidermodder/embroideryviewer/MainActivity.java), tentei procurar nesse `app` onde fica método ou comando invocado para exibir esse lista de dados segue prints da tela para exemplificar.
  Gostaria de saber onde fica o método chamado para exibir a lista de dados da imagem 2, neste projeto ?

[image: Ícone ou botão do navigationView]

[image: Lista de dados]

Segue o código da `MainActivity`

```
package com.embroidermodder.embroideryviewer;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EmbPattern.Provider {
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 100;
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS_LOAD = 101;
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS_READ = 102;
    private static final String TEMPFILE = "TEMP";
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.embroidermodder.embroideryviewer";
    String drawerFragmentTag;
    private final int SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private DrawView drawView;
    private DrawerLayout mainActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        threadLoadIntent(intent);

        mainActivity = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity);
        drawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.drawview);
        drawView.initWindowSize();

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, mainActivity, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        mainActivity.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if ((getPattern() != null) && (!getPattern().isEmpty())) {
            saveInternalFile(TEMPFILE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if ((getPattern() == null) || (getPattern().isEmpty())) {
            loadInternalFile(TEMPFILE);
        }
    }

    public void saveInternalFile(String filename) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            EmbWriter writer = new EmbWriterEmm();
            writer.write(getPattern(), fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException ioerror) {
        }
    }


    public void loadInternalFile(String filename) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename); //if no file exists, throws error.
            EmbReader reader = new EmbReaderEmm();
            EmbPattern pattern = new EmbPattern();
            reader.read(pattern, fis);
            setPattern(pattern);
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ignored) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (dialogDismiss()) {
            return;
        }
        if (tryCloseFragment(ShareFragment.TAG)) {
            return;
        }
        if (mainActivity.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mainActivity.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { //requires single instance mode, else this does nothing.
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        threadLoadIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_open_file:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"), SELECT_FILE);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_show_statistics:
                showStatistics();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_share:
                useShareFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.action_load_file:
                dialogDismiss();
                makeDialog(R.layout.embroidery_thumbnail_view);
                saveFileWrapper(new PermissionRequired() {
                    @Override
                    public void openExternalStorage(File root, String data) {
                        loadFile(root, data);
                    }
                }, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    saveFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.write_permissions_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS_LOAD:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    loadFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.write_permissions_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS_READ:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    threadLoadIntent(getIntent()); //restarts the load of the intent.
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.read_permissions_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                threadLoadIntent(data);
            }
        }
    }

    interface PermissionRequired {
        void openExternalStorage(File root, String data);
    }

    private void saveFileWrapper(PermissionRequired permissionRequired, File root, String data) {
        int hasWriteExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (hasWriteExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                showMessageOKCancel(getString(R.string.external_storage_justification),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                            }
                        });
                return;
            }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
        permissionRequired.openExternalStorage(root, data);
    }

    private void callIfLoadIntentStreamIsUnreadableWithoutPermissions() {
        int hasReadExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (hasReadExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                showMessageOKCancel(getString(R.string.external_storage_justification_read),
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS_READ);
                            }
                        });
                return;
            }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS_READ);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void loadFile(File root, String data) {
        GridView list = (GridView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.embroideryThumbnailList);
        File mPath = new File(root + "");
        list.setAdapter(new ThumbnailAdapter(MainActivity.this, mPath));
    }

    private void saveFile(File root, String data) {
        //todo: this really only save one jef to the root directory. Decide what needs to be done.
        try {
            int n = 10000;
            Random generator = new Random();
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String filename = "Image-" + n + ".jef";
            IFormat.Writer format = IFormat.getWriterByFilename(filename);
            if (format != null) {
                File file = new File(root, filename);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                format.write(drawView.getPattern(), outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Dialog dialog;
    View dialogView;

    public boolean dialogDismiss() {
        if ((dialog != null) && (dialog.isShowing())) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Dialog makeDialog(int layout) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        if (isFinishing()) {
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        } else {
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dialog.show();
            return dialog;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, okListener)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    public void useShareFragment() {
        dialogDismiss();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ShareFragment fragment = new ShareFragment();
        transaction.add(R.id.mainContentArea, fragment, ShareFragment.TAG);
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    public void useColorFragment() {
        if (drawerFragmentTag != null) {
            tryCloseFragment(drawerFragmentTag);
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ColorStitchBlockFragment fragment = new ColorStitchBlockFragment();
        drawerFragmentTag = ColorStitchBlockFragment.TAG;
        transaction.add(R.id.drawerContent, fragment, ColorStitchBlockFragment.TAG);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public boolean tryCloseFragment(String tag) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragmentByTag;
        fragmentByTag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (fragmentByTag == null) return false;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(fragmentByTag);
        transaction.commit();
        if (fragmentByTag instanceof EmbPattern.Listener) {
            EmbPattern pattern = getPattern();
            if (pattern != null) {
                pattern.removeListener((EmbPattern.Listener) fragmentByTag);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void toast(final int stringResource) {
        if (!Looper.getMainLooper().equals(Looper.myLooper())) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toast(stringResource);
                }
            });
            return;
        }
        Toast toast;
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, stringResource, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

    public void showStatistics() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(drawView.getStatistics());
        builder.show();
    }

    public EmbPattern getPattern() {
        if (drawView == null) return null;
        return drawView.getPattern();
    }

    public void setPattern(final EmbPattern pattern) {
        if (!Looper.getMainLooper().equals(Looper.myLooper())) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setPattern(pattern);
                }
            });
            return;
        }
        drawView.setPattern(pattern);
        getPattern().notifyChange(EmbPattern.NOTIFY_LOADED);
        drawView.invalidate();
        useColorFragment();
    }


    public void threadLoadIntent(final Intent intent) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadFromIntent(intent);
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }


    public Uri getUriFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null) return uri;

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle == null) return null;

        Object object = bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (object instanceof Uri) {
            return (Uri) object;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected String getDisplayNameByUri(Uri uri) {
        String filename = null;
        if (uri.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("content")) {
            Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            if ((returnCursor != null) && (returnCursor.getCount() != 0)) {
                int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                if (returnCursor.moveToFirst()) filename = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
                returnCursor.close();
            }
        } else {
            filename = uri.getPath();
        }
        return filename;
    }

    protected void loadFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null) return;
        if (intent.hasExtra("done")) return;
        intent.putExtra("done", 1);

        Uri uri = getUriFromIntent(intent);
        if (uri == null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) || Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) || Intent.ACTION_EDIT.equals(action)) {
                //todo: toast error message about the URI not being read.
            }
            return;
        }

        IFormat.Reader reader = null;
        String mime = intent.getType();
        //reader = IFormat.getReaderByMime(mime); Sometimes the intent *only* has the MIME type and does not have an extention.

        if (reader == null) {
            String name = getDisplayNameByUri(uri);
            //String ext = IFormat.getExtentionByDisplayName(name);
            //if (ext == null) {
            //Toast error message about how the extension doesn't exist and there's no way to know what the file is without mimetype or extension.
            //return;
            //}
            reader = IFormat.getReaderByFilename(name);
            if (reader == null) {
                toast(R.string.file_type_not_supported);
                return;
            }
        }
        //I have a reader.
        EmbPattern pattern = null;
        switch (uri.getScheme().toLowerCase()) {
            case "http":
            case "https":
                HttpURLConnection connection;
                URL url;

                try {
                    url = new URL(uri.toString());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    toast(R.string.error_file_not_found);
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_LENGTH_REQUIRED);
                    connection.setReadTimeout(1000);
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                    pattern = new EmbPattern();
                    reader.read(pattern, in);
                    in.close();
                    connection.disconnect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    toast(R.string.error_file_read_failed);
                    return;
                }
                break;
            case "content":
            case "file":
                try {
                    InputStream fis = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    pattern = new EmbPattern();
                    reader.read(pattern, fis);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    toast(R.string.error_file_not_found);
                    return;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    toast(R.string.error_file_read_failed);
                }
                break;
        }
        if (pattern != null) {
            setPattern(pattern);
            drawView.postInvalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tenta explicar o que está tentando fazer que as vezes é mais fácil.

Comment: @AllanBraga o que estou tentando fazer seria aproveitar o mesmo método que pega os dados igual da figura 2, e jogar outro lugar por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Começa em `DrawView` apos ser feito a injeçao no navigationView.

```
drawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.drawview);
drawView.initWindowSize();

ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mainActivity, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
mainActivity.addDrawerListener(toggle);
```

DrawView implementa 2 classes EmbPattern.Listener, EmbPattern.Provider

Dentro de DrawView existe declarado a classe paint que é uma biblioteca nativa.

```
Paint _paint = new Paint();
```

No contrustor de DrawView é chamado o método init que define o tamanho do quadro

```
public void init() {
       _paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
       _paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
       embPattern.addListener(this);
}
```

A interface `EmbPattern.Provider` que é implementada declara um metodo

`EmbPatter.Java` possui a interface que é implementada em DrawView e declara somente 1 método

```
public interface Provider {
   EmbPattern getPattern();
}
```

Esse método é implementado retornando uma nova classe EmbPattern.

```
@Override
public EmbPattern getPattern() {
    return embPattern;
}
```

E o RecyclerView com a logíca para preencher o NavigationView é a classe `ColorStitchAdapter.java`

Se você olhar dentro dela tem o método que determina se é texto ou cor.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case METADATA:
                MetaDataViewHolder mHolder = (MetaDataViewHolder) holder;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        mHolder.setDataPair(EmbPattern.PROP_FILENAME,pattern.filename);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mHolder.setDataPair(EmbPattern.PROP_NAME,pattern.name);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mHolder.setDataPair(EmbPattern.PROP_AUTHOR,pattern.author);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mHolder.setDataPair(EmbPattern.PROP_CATEGORY,pattern.category);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        mHolder.setDataPair(EmbPattern.PROP_KEYWORDS,pattern.keywords);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        mHolder.setDataPair(EmbPattern.PROP_COMMENTS,pattern.comments);
                }
                break;
            case STITCH:
                ColorStitchStitchViewHolder sHolder = (ColorStitchStitchViewHolder) holder;
                Point p = pattern.getStitches().getPoint((position - 6) - pattern.getThreadCount());
                sHolder.setPoint(p);
                break;
            case COLOR:
                ColorStitchColorViewHolder cHolder = (ColorStitchColorViewHolder) holder;
                EmbThread thread = pattern.getThreadlist().get(position-6);
                cHolder.setThread(thread);
                break;
        }
    }
```

`EmbPatternViewer.java` - Responsavel por Pintar os quadros como na imagem 2
`getThumbnail` retorna uma imagem com os quadros pintados utilizando um array

```
public Bitmap getThumbnail(float _width, float _height) {
        RectF viewPort = calculateBoundingBox();
        float scale = Math.min(_height / viewPort.height(), _width / viewPort.width());
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (scale != 0) {
            matrix.postTranslate(-viewPort.left, -viewPort.top);
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
        }

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) _width, (int) _height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        if (matrix != null) canvas.concat(matrix);
        for (StitchBlock stitchBlock : this) {
            stitchBlock.draw(canvas, paint); // pinta os quadros do 
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Método dentro de `StitchBlock.java`

```
  public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
        if (_thread == null) return;
        paint.setColor(_thread.getColor());

        int count = (getIndex_stop() - getIndex_start()) << 1;
        int start = getIndex_start() << 1;
        if (count >= 4) {
            if ((count & 2) != 0) {
                canvas.drawLines(list.pointlist, start + 0, count - 2, paint);
                canvas.drawLines(list.pointlist, start + 2, count - 2, paint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawLines(list.pointlist, start + 0, count, paint);
                canvas.drawLines(list.pointlist, start + 2, count - 4, paint);
            }
        }
    }
```

E como saber de onde ele pega os itens

Em main activity há uma chamada pra o método que carrega os itens e adiciona no Pattern.

```
public void loadInternalFile(String filename) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename); //if no file exists, throws error.
            EmbReader reader = new EmbReaderEmm();
            EmbPattern pattern = new EmbPattern();
            reader.read(pattern, fis);
            setPattern(pattern);
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ignored) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu baixei o projeto e rodei como `debug`. A linha 75 é a responsável por delegar ao `DrawerLayout` a função de escultar os eventos de clique no `menu sandwich`

```
mainActivity.addDrawerListener(toggle);
```

Se você quiser interceptar os eventos de clique, coloque `break points` dentro da classe `DrawerLayout`

Comment: ok, mas eu precisava do método que em que pega os dados igual da figura 2.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse trecho

```
   mainActivity = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity);
    drawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.drawview);
    drawView.initWindowSize();

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mainActivity, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    mainActivity.addDrawerListener(toggle);
```

A variável `mainActivity` é a view que tem os dados

Comment: ok, mas eu precisava do método que em que pega os dados igual da figura 2.

Comment: Esses dados são preenchidos em outro lugar

Comment: Marceloawq essa minha dúvida, pois gostaria de chamar esse mesmo método